# Yet another case where Composer will not install

Tags: php, apache, openssl, installation, composer-php

For the past 3 days I have read through all of the questions related to composer installation issues here and on many other blogs, and have tried everything recommended but still cannot get it to install. Here is a summary.

```
php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2013 21:01:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Uncommented `extension=php_openssl.dll` and `extension_dir = "ext"` in the following files:

- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini
- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini-development
- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini-production
- C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

From php -i:
        openssl

```
    OpenSSL support => enabled
    OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
    OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

    extension_dir => ext => ext
```

Composer installer found php.exe in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe`

Composer installation settings:

```
    PHP version 5.4.16
          C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe

    Add to System path variable:
          C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

    Shell Menus: 
          Do not install
```

Composer Installer error:

```
    Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
    file_get_contents(HYPERLINK HAD TO BE REMOVED TO ASK FOR HELP): failed to open stream: operation failed
    Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
    file_get_contents(HYPERLINK HAD TO BE REMOVED TO ASK FOR HELP): failed to open stream: operation failed
    Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
    file_get_contents(HYPERLINK HAD TO BE REMOVED TO ASK FOR HELP): failed to open stream: operation failed
    The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

and

```
    php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
    All settings correct for using Composer
    Downloading...
    Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
    file_get_contents(HYPERLINK HAD TO BE REMOVED TO ASK FOR HELP): failed to open stream:
     operation failed
    Downloading...
    Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
    Error messages:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
    file_get_contents(HYPERLINK HAD TO BE REMOVED TO ASK FOR HELP): failed to open stream:
     operation failed
    Downloading...
    Download failed: file_get_contents(HYPERLINK HAD TO BE REMOVED TO ASK FOR HELP): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
    Error messages:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
    file_get_contents(): failed to open stream:
     operation failed
    The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

The Removed hyperlinks all pointed to : https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

I hope someone has some new ideas, because I am about to learn how Composer works so I can manually install the package that requires Composer.

PHP is great IF you can get all of the packages to work. But it can takes days of frustration to get things that should be simple, like Composer, to actually work.

Comment: I would suggest using Docker. From the [`php:7-alpine3.8` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) I was able to `apk add composer` out of the box. Save yourself the pain...

Answer (score -2):

I too was having this problem when running from the terminal the command:

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

However I found that running this from the terminal downloaded composer.phar successfully:

echo "https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar') ?>" | php > composer.phar